# Which of the following tasks dont always spent a consistent amount of time?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make the loading part of a C# program faster. Currently it takes like 15 seconds to load up.
On first glimpse, things that are done during the loading part includes constructing many 3rd Party UI components, loading layout files, xmls, DLLs, resources files, reflections, waiting for WndProc... etc.

I used something really simple to see the time some part takes, 
i.e. breakpointing at a double which holds the total milliseconds of a TimeSpan which is the difference of a DateTime.Now at the start and a DateTime.Now at the end.
Trying that a few times will give me sth like,
11s 13s 12s 12s 7s 11s 12s 11s 7s 13s 7s.. (Usually 12s, but 7s sometimes)

If I add SuspendLayout, BeginUpdate like hell; call things in reflections once instead of many times; reduce some redundant redundant computation redundancy. The time are like 3s 4s 3s 4s 3s 10s 4s 4s 3s 4s 10s 3s 10s.... (Usually 4s, but 10s sometimes)

In both cases, the times are not consistent but more like, a bimodal distribution? It really made me unsure whether my correction of the code is really making it faster.
So I would like to know what will cause such result.
Debug mode?
The "C# hve to compile/interpret the code on the 1st time it runs, but the following times will be faster" thing?
The waiting of WndProc message?
The reflections? PropertyInfo? Reflection.Assembly? 
Loading files? XML? DLL? resource file?
UI Layouts?
(There are surely no internet/network/database access in that part)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Profiling by stopping in the debugger is not a reliable way to get timings, as you've discovered.

Profiling by writing times to a log works fine, although why do all this by hand when you can just launch the program in dotTrace? (Free trial, fully functional).

Another thing that works when you don't have access to a profiler is what I call the binary approach - look at what happens in the code and try to disable about half of it by using comments. Note the effect on the running time. If it appears significant, repeat this process with half of that half, and so on recursively until you narrow in on the most significant piece of work. The difficulty is in simulating the side effects of the missing code so that that the remaining code can still work, so this is still harder than using a debugger, but can be quicker than adding a lot of manually time logging, because the binary approach lets you zero in on the slowest place in logarithmic time.

Raymond Chen's advise is good here. When people ask him "How can I make my application start up faster?" [he says "Do less stuff."](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/scobleizer/Raymond-Chen-PDC-05-Talk-Five-Things-Every-Win32-Programmer-Needs-to-Know/)

(And ALWAYS profile the release build - profiling the debug build is generally a wasted effort).

Answer (score 0):

Profile it. you can use [eqatec](http://www.eqatec.com/) its free

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best thing is to run your application through a profiler and see what the bottlenecks are. I've personally used [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), there are plenty of others you can find on the web.

Debug mode turns off a lot of JIT optimizations, so apps will run a lot slower than release builds. Whatever the mode, JITting has to happen, so I'd discount that as a significant factor. Time to read files from disk can vary based on the OS's caching mechanism, and whether you're doing a cold start or a warm start.

If you have to use timers to profile, I'd suggest repeating the experiment a large number of times and taking the average.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling you code is definitely the best way to identify which areas are taking the longest to run.

As for the other part of your question about the inconsistent timings: timings in an multitasking O/S are inherently inconsistent, and working with managed code throws the garbage collector into the equation too. It could be that the GC is kicking in during your timing which will obviously slow things down.

If you want to try and get a "purer" timing try putting a GC collect before you start your timers, this way it is less likely to start in your timing section. Do remember to remove the timers after, as second guessing when the GC should run normally results in poorer performance.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious (profiling), which will tell you precisely where time is being spent, there are some other points that spring to mind:

- To get reasonable timing results with the approach you are using, run a **release** build of your program, and have it dump the timing results to a file (e.g. with Trace.WriteLine). Timing a debug version will give you spurious results. When running the timing tests, quit all other applications (including your debugger) to minimise the load on your computer and get more consistent results. Run the program many times and look at the average timings. Finally, bear in mind that Windows caches a lot of stuff, so the first run will be slow and subsequent runs will be much faster. This will at least give you a more consistent basis to tell whether your improvements are making a significant difference.
- Don't try and optimise code that shouldn't be run in the first place - Can you defer any of the init tasks? You may find that some of the work can simply be removed from the init sequence. e.g. if you are loading a data file, check whether it is needed immediately - if not, then you could load it the first time it is needed instead of during program startup.